# Find the number of rows in ~ 1000 CSV's using command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm running a process that produces n number of outputs at different timestamps for a given input CSV. The output files are in CSV form and labelled as such:

"Output" _ RouteName _ Direction _ YYMMDD _ HHMMSS

I have a macro that reports on missing data in the files, I just need a list of the number of rows in each CSV. 
I have been doing this by using the command:

```
@Echo Off
:_Loop
If "%~1"=="" Pause&Goto EOF
Find /C /V "Wont@findthisin#anyfile" %1 >> LineCount.txt
Shift
Goto _Loop
```

The command is called counter.cmd and I just drag the output CSV's into it and it creates this output in a text file for each output:

```
---------- R:\10_TECHNICAL\10_TESTRUN\RUN\AM\ITN\A6_1N\OUTPUT_A6_1N_180313_070112.CSV: 5
```

The problem is that, I can only use this command to process a maximum of ~ 100 files, and I have ~ 1000 output files. When I try to make it do all 1000 files I get this error:

[image: Error]

I have relatively basic windows command scripting skills and so don't know how to overcome this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to assume the restriction is with your `%1` variable and the maximum allowed command line length.

This can probably be easily remedied with a single command line

```bat
@Find /C /V "" R:\10_Technical\10_TestRun\Run\AM\ITN\A6_1N\*.csv > LineCount.txt
```

**Edit**

You can drag and drop the folder containing your csv files onto the batch file too.

If you want the outputfile in the same directory as the csv's then use:

```bat
@Find /C /V "" "%~1\*.csv" > "%~1\LineCount.txt"
```

Or in the same directory as the batch file:

```bat
@Find /C /V "" "%~1\*.csv" > "%~dp0LineCount.txt"
```

You could even have it output to the directory holding that folder:

```bat
@Find /C /V "" "%~1\*.csv" > "LineCount.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a dream

Comment: No problem, I've added a couple of examples as an edit, which may also be helpful. _Please also consider marking your preferred solution as accepted._

Answer (score 4):

Before I get to the source of your problem, and the fix, I want to point out a couple things that could improve your current script.

1) Your FIND command can be simplified to `find /n /v "" filePath` - it seems nonsensical, but it works.

2) GOTO is relatively slow. You can get rid of the GOTO loop by using the FOR command to process all of the arguments. You can use `%*` to retrieve all of the arguments.

3) Every time you redirect the file must be opened and the file pointer positioned to the end of file. This takes time. It is much faster to redirect only once.

Incorporating all of the above, your script could be as simple as

```
@echo off
> LineCount.txt (for %%F in (%*) do find /n /v "" "%%F")
pause
```

When you drag files onto a batch script, it creates a single command line containing the path to each of the files. A Windows command line is limited to 8191 bytes long. So there is no way your strategy will work if you have ~1000 files.

I'm assuming all of your files are within a single folder, in which case you could change your script to process a single folder path instead of a list of file paths.

```
@echo off
>LineCount.txt (for %%F in ("%~1\*.csv") do find /n /v "" "%%F")
pause
```

If the files are spread across a few folders, then you can add an extra loop to iterate each of the folders

```
@echo off
>LineCount.txt ( for %%A in (%*) do for %%F in ("%%~A\*.csv") do find /n /v "" %%F")
pause
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your prompt reply. Somethings I'm not quite sure of as I'm a complete novice. I'm not sure where to set the path in the script. How exactly do i use that code? Once again apologies for the basic questions.

Comment: @Abuz1994 you drag and drop the folder.